# JavaScript - setTimeout() / clearTimeout()

Tags: javascript

Why does this function print out `0 1 2` instead of `0 1 2 3`?

```
(function fn1(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var tc=setTimeout(function(i){
            console.log(i);
            clearTimeout(tc);
        }, 10, i);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Why do you clear the timeout?

Comment: It was a question asked in interview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var` gets hoisted, of course, so in the `for` loop `tc` gets (synchronously) reassigned multiple times and ends up as the *final* `setTimeout`. So, each time the timeout function runs, it references the same `tc` that references the final iteration's timeout and clears it with `clearTimeout`. To the interpreter, it looks like this:

```js
(function fn1() {
  var tc;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tc = setTimeout(function(i) {
      console.log(i);
      clearTimeout(tc);
    }, 10, i);
  }
})();
```

If you wanted to print out `0 1 2 3`, use `let` instead (`let` has block scope, and is not hoisted) to give each iteration a separate binding for `tc`:

```js
(function fn1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let tc = setTimeout(function(i) {
      console.log(i);
      clearTimeout(tc);
    }, 10, i);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful~